# Can I make a smart pointer to a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am brand new to C++ (and Stack Overflow!) so I apologize if this question has already been answered in some capacity, I just wasn't able to find exactly what I was looking for.

In a recent project, I created pointers to pointers (example: Tiger **tigerArray;) and wound up having memory leaks in my program, but I was never able to figure out why. I had a thought that maybe if I had done smart pointers instead of just pointers, that may have solved the problem?

So I'm curious, if I can create a pointer to a pointer, can I create a smart pointer to a smart pointer?

**Sorry I should update, I wasn't allowed to use vectors for this assignment, we had to use arrays

Comment: You can but what it sounds like you really want is a `std::vector<std::vector<Tiger>>`

Comment: Did you try? What happened? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If you wanted `Tiger** tigerArray` to represent a 2D array then smart-pointer-to-smart-pointer is likely not what you wanted, but maybe `std::vector<std::vector<Tiger>>` instead?

Comment: If you can't use vectors then I doubt they will let you use smart pointers.  What you should do is write your own vector like class (you don't need all the bells and whistles vector gives you) and then you can use that instead.

Comment: @CoryKramer apologies, very new to all of this so when searching "smart pointer to smart pointer" I got a lot of answers about smart pointers themselves (what they are, using one to point to functions, etc), but not necessarily about pointing one to another one - I will remove this question if it seems out of place - the problem really could just be that I don't know enough about them/C++ in general to recognize that the answer could already be in one of those questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smart points are generic; you can stick basically anything you want inside one. But you should decide the right tool for the job based on what it is you're trying to achieve. Smart pointers have fairly specific use cases. Pointers to pointers, on the other hand, have a couple different use cases:

- pointer arrays of pointer arrays, for implementing 2D arrays. If this is what you're trying to achieve, consider using `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` or `std::array<std::array<T, N>, M>` if you know your array will always have size `M`x`N`.
- pointer to a pointer, as used for modifying another pointer from a function. In this case, you should consider passing by reference. If you really need pointers in your code, you could modify one by passing as `T*&`, a reference to a pointer to `T`. But depending on what you're representing, you could just as well pass your data as `std::vector<T>&`, for example.

Smart pointers exist to automatically manage the lifetime of objects depending on how you want those objects to be used. They don't exist purely as a means of indirection that is open to many different usages, like raw pointers. My advice on which tool to use would be as follows:

- If you need a simple resizable array of `T`, use `std::vector<T>`.
- If you need a 2D resizable array of `T`, use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`.
- If you know you will always have `N` elements in your array, consider using `std::array<T, N>`.
- If you need more structure, such as strict ordering or relationships, consider using `std::set`, `std::map`, `std::multimap`, `std::queue`, `std::stack`, etc

About smart pointers:

- If you need an object that is light-weight to pass around but only ever has a single owner, or if you need to encapsulate a polymorphic object that is used in a single place, consider `std::unique_ptr<T>`
- If you need an object to be used by multiple places in code which does not have a single sensible place of ownership and instead needs to have distributed ownership, use `std::shared_ptr<T>`
- If you want to modify an object from inside a function such that the object will live for the duration of the function's needs, just pass by reference: `T&`
- If you want to read from but not modify an object in a function where that object will be alive for the duration of the function's needs, pass by reference to const: `const T&`

EDIT:

After seeing that you are not allowed to use `std::vector` for your assignment, I realize I'm not really answering your updated question. But I still hope to give you (and future readers) some insight as to what smart pointers are for and what they're not for.

If your instructor is teaching C++ but not allowing you to use `vector`s, I would criticize them by saying that `vector` is an immensely important tool on the belt of the modern C++ developer, and its usage is far simpler and safer than the C-style alternatives that are still taught as being C++ in many outdated curriculums. The same goes other tools and techniques such as generally avoiding pointers, avoiding `new` and `delete`, and making good use of the containers and algorithms of the standard library, all of which helps you write cleaner, correcter, and efficient code.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. What I'm understanding is that smart pointers go in hand with vectors, and really don't have an application such as a "smart pointer to a smart pointer".

Comment: @eckmo That's correct. `vector` is for when you need an array and smart pointers are when you need to solve tricky ownership problems. You're free to create a vector of smart pointers or a smart pointer to a vector or other such compositions, depending on what you need.